# ffmpeg multiple inputs ss on only one of them

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to put audio on top of video.

I use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 out
```

But I want the audio to start at 0:28 (the zeroth second of out's audio is the 28th second of audio's audio)

So I tried

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -ss 28 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 out
```

I had hoped that since I did -ss after audio specifically it would be applied only to that input, but actually the video is also started at 28 seconds in.

How can I include the video entirely, but skip the first 28 seconds of the input audio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seek on inputs go *before* that input.

```
ffmpeg -i video -ss 28 -i audio -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 out
```